# Изменить порядок пунктов меню в админке WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Есть ли возможность сделать пункты меню "рубрики" и "записи" дочерними пользовательского пункта меню?

Comment: Есть. Почитайте вот эту статью: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-your-wordpress-admin--wp-24941

Comment: упсс. Про какое "меню" речь?

Comment: Меню в админке имеется ввиду, для клиента нужно сделать пункт верхнего уровня, а в подменю добавить стандартные страницы редактирования записей, категорий, произвольные типы записей и т.д

Comment: Про то что упоминается в статье) все верно. Вот только дочерние пункты нужно не удалять а переместить

Answer (score 0):

Конечно есть. Всё мышей двигается.

**Доб**.
Если речь про пункты самой админки, то есть плагины. Напр. https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Comment: Спасибо, плагин уже рассматривал как вариант. Но хотелось бы сделать все из собственного плагина.

Comment: От скуки? Чтобы потом клиент ломал голову и себе и на форумах почему у него не так как нужно и как это исправить?

Comment: Нет не от скуки, а по просьбе клиента, что бы был один пункт с которым она работает.

Comment: Вопрос "что бы был один пункт с которым она работает" решается на уровне разделения ролей и возможностей, а не скрытием пунктов админки. А плагинофобия - зло. Тем более когда речь о плагах для управления админкой.

Answer (score 0):

Внешний вид ---> Меню и там все можно настроить. Только вам придётся для этого создать новое меню, а потом уже его изменять + ставите галочку "Главное меню" и всё это сохраняете